# SparkSQLContext dataframe Select query based on column array

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my dataframe:

```
  authors: array (nullable = true)-->
    element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I want to select all books where the author is Udo Haiber.

```
spark.sql("select *  from f  where authors="Udo Haiber" ").show
```

but of course it didn't work because authors is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_contains` to check if the author is inside the array:

```
spark.sql("select * from f where array_contains(authors, 'Udo Haiber')")
```

Use single quotes to quote the author name because you're using double quotes for the query string.